# Difference Between Feynman-Kac PDE and Kolmogorov Backward Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose $X_u$ satisfies the SDE 
$$
dX_u = a(u, X_u) du + b(u,X_u) dW_u\;.
$$
Fix $T > 0$ and let $X_t = x$ for $0 \leq t \leq T$ be given.  For any measurable function $h$, define
$$
g(t,x) = E^{t,x}(h(X_T))\;.
$$
Then $g$ satisfies the [Feynman-Kac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)
$$
g_t(t,x) + a(t, x) g_x(t,x) + \frac{1}{2}b^2(t,x)g_{xx}(t,x) = 0
$$
with terminal condition
$$
g(T,x) = h(x) \;.
$$
Fair enough, but now consider the Kolmogorov backward equation.  Let $p(t,x; T, y)$ be the transition density of $X_u$; i.e., if $X_t = x$, then $X_T$ has density $p(t,x; T,y)$ in the $y$ variable.  Then for each $T$ and $y$, $p$ satisfies the [Kolmogorov backward equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_backward_equations_%28diffusion%29)
$$
p_t(t,x; T,y) + a(t,x)p_x(t,x;T,y) + \frac{1}{2}b^2(t,x)p_{xx}(t,x;, T,y) = 0
$$
with terminal condition
$$
p(T,x; T,y) = u_T(x)
$$
for some function $u_T(x)$

As far as I can tell, these are the same equations; the only difference between the solutions being the terminal conditions.  Is this a correct understanding?  Is there some greater insight as to why these aren't both called the same equation?  I see that $g$ and $p$ are related by
$$
g(t,x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(y) p(x,t;T,y)\,dy
$$
but I'm not seeing anything insightful from this relationship, and am afraid I'm missing something.  I've read the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319035/motivation-of-feynman-kac-formula-and-its-relation-to-kolmogorov-backward-forwar) but am still a bit unsure of the difference.

Comment: if $X_t = x$, then $X_T$ has density $p(t,x; T,y)$ in the $y$ variable -- by so $p$ is conditional density, not transition density

Answer (score 2):

I hate to resurrect a four year old question with an only-partially-helpful response, but [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjSvZiG5sLuAhVHw1kKHUUyCYwQFjAFegQIDhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1007%2FBF02673625.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0u6SVvhbefJkz3gyW6AkRa&cshid=1611980172810216) shows that Feynman-Kac is the same as a Kolmogorov backward equation. I haven't read it in detail, so I can't summarise and do it any justice, but hopefully it helps you. In case the link doesn't work, paper is: VERSIONS OF THE FEYNMAN-KAC FORMULA by A N Borodin.

Great question!